# How to make a function excute before an other function

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

i have a search input and i hope to make a "live-search"
i mean when the user change the value of the input-text the
 result update ! i use react-native and sqlite as a local database

Now the result is the function of "set_state" excute after the function of "search_user" ! when i put the
 user_id "2" i dont recive any result but when i delete the "2" i recive the result of "2" so i conclure that t
hese two functions must excute the seconde after the first ! if you have an other solution or how to fix this problem please ?

```
      searchUser = () => {
    const { input_user_id } = this.state;
    console.log(this.state.input_user_id);
    db.transaction(tx => {
      tx.executeSql(
        'SELECT * FROM table_user where user_id = ?',
        [input_user_id],
        (tx, results) => {
          var len = results.rows.length;
          console.log('len', len);
          if (len > 0) {
            this.setState({
              userData: results.rows.item(0),
            });
          } else {
            alert('No user found');
            this.setState({
              userData: '',
            });
          }
        }
      );
    });
  };

      constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input_user_id: '',
      userData: '',
    };
  }
```

and this is my textinput

```
<Mytextinput
         placeholder="Enter User Id"
         onChangeText={input_user_id => {this.searchUser(this); this.setState({ input_user_id });  }}
         style={{ padding:10 }}
       />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why do not you pass input_user_id  directly to the function ?
otherwise you can do

```
this.setState({input_user_id }, () => this.searchUser(this))
```

Comment: thank you i try your reponse and it's work but you can explain more please ?

Answer (score 2):

setState in react [is asynchronous](https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-setstate-a4640451865b)

you can use callbacks to do something after setState has finished this way -

```
searchUser(callback_func) => {
    //... code here
    this.setState({
          userData: '',
    }, () => { callback_func(status); });   // status is not required, but you can signify failures this way
}

// now you can use searchUser like this -
searchUser(status => {
    //do this when set state done
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes !
when you do

```
function(input_user_id) {
  this.searchUser(this);
  this.setState({ input_user_id })
}
```

both functions run in order, but setState is asynchronous.

So when you do

```
  const { input_user_id } = this.state;
```

the state has not been updated yet.

As you can pass a callback function to setState,

you make sure that input_user_id will be updated before this.searchUser() is executed

```
this.setState({input_user_id }, () => this.searchUser(this))
```